# Python bug - ImportError: No module named _weakrefset

Tags: python, pycharm

I have this problem with a new installation of pycharm. I saw another entry having the same problem with dreamhost. However the actual reason for the bug was not explained.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 68, in <module>
    import os
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 398, in <module>
    import UserDict
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 83, in <module>
    import _abcoll
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py", line 11, in <module>
    from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/abc.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _weakrefset import WeakSet
ImportError: No module named _weakrefset
```

The python version is 2.7.6 and is up-to-date in Linux Mint 17.1

_weakrefset does exist on my system

```
locate weakrefset
/usr/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc
```

so I'm at a loss how to resolve this bug. 
Any tips much appreciated!

Comment: did you `pip install weakrefset` ?

Comment: It's not an OS package in Linux Mint, so it can't be installed with apt-get. But as you can see from the locate, it's there.

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming your site.py file.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15377

I had the same issue and it stopped when I changed the name.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to or I've no privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this: edit your *Run Configuration* and uncheck "*add content roots to PYTHONPATH*".